# Why doesn't my Xamarin.Forms Entry get empty in the UI when I set the bound string to ""?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I use the following method to set my variables:

```
    private string _password = "";
    public string Password
    {
        get => _password;
        set {
            _password = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Password");
            this.OnPropertyChanged("_password");
        }
    }
```

This is within my ViewModel that I bind via:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:MainPageViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

I have a Entry in my xaml with:

```
<Entry Text="{Binding Password,Mode=TwoWay}"                               
   HorizontalOptions="Start"
   VerticalOptions="Start">
</Entry>
```

I have no problem accessing the information in the entry within my ViewModel however when I call

```
Password = "";
```

The text of the Entry that gets shown within the UI on the screen stays the same. How do I erase the text within the Entry from my ViewModel?
The behavior happens in Android/iOS and UWP.

Comment: does your VM actually implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following changes and it should work for you :

remove this `this.OnPropertyChanged("_password");` as you notify on property changed and not on the field changed.

Hence it would look like:

```
 public string Password
{
    get => _password;
    set {
        _password = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("Password");           
    }
}
```

Secondly, In my knowledge, you might want to do the Password change on MainThread something like:

```
 Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { Password = string.Empty; });
```

The reason being `INotifyPropertyChanged` is not thread safe! and you could be doing it in an async method

Comment: Thanks, using `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` was what helped me.